# How do I horizontally align a group of radio buttons (and labels) when using display:flex to stack them side by side

Tags: html, css

I have used `display:flex` to style a number of radio buttons so that they appear side by side, rather than in one long column. I thought by using `margin:auto` in combination with this, the child elements would appear grouped but in the center of the page horizontally. Clearly this isn't the case, so any help would be appreciated please.

Here is what I have currently:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18vw;
}
label {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 4vw;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section style="display:flex; margin:auto;">
    <div>
        <p>Amount:</p>
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="Amount" id="Amount1" value="single" / checked>
        <label for="Amount1">Amount 1</label>
        </br>
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="Amount" id="Amount2" value="multi" />
        <label for="Amount2">Amount 2</label>
    </div>
    <span style="width:5vw;display:inline-block"></span>
    <div>
        <p>Term:</p>
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="Term" id="Term1" value="0" / checked>
        <label for="Term1">Term 1</label>
        </br>
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="Term" id="Term2" value="1" />
        <label for="Term2">Term 2</label>
    </div>
    <span style="width:5vw;display:inline-block"></span>
    <div>
        <p>Phone:</p>
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="Phone" id="Phone1" value="0" / checked>
        <label for="Phone1">Phone 1</label>
        </br>
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="Phone" id="Phone2" value="1" />
        <label for="Phone2">Phone 2</label>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have used viewport width throughout the project, as I have further CSS styling to change element sizes based on media queries. So I need a solution that still keeps this styling if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following should help:

```
justify-content: center
```

On the `display:flex` class.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I knew there was a simple answer I just wasn't aware of. I will accept answer when able to do so.

Comment: Glad to help! I recommend you to read the source link I added. Flexbox is very powerful if you know how to use it.

Comment: I have bookmarked and will certainly get to grips with it, thanks.